# How to solve error message about squirrel mail (ERROR: Connection dropped by IMAP)

Tags: squirrelmail

I was setup squirrel mail in centos 6.4

and, i was installed imap(dovecot), squirrelmail, sendmail completely.

and open, port 110, 143, 25.

and, setting a squirrelmail about imap (through ./conf.pl)

and, i accessed a squirrel mail cite. ( domain/src/configtest.php).

... you can read below text.

---

## SquirrelMail configtest

This script will try to check some aspects of your SquirrelMail configuration
and point you to errors whereever it can find them. You need to go run conf.pl
in the config/ directory first before you run this script.

SquirrelMail version:**1.4.22-3.el6**
Config file version:**1.4.0**
Config file last modified:**22 June 2013 00:53:13**

Checking PHP configuration...
    PHP version 5.3.3 OK.

Running as N/A(N/A) / N/A(N/A)
    display_errors: 
    error_reporting: 22527
    variables_order OK: GPCS.
    PHP extensions OK. Dynamic loading is disabled.
Checking paths...
    Data dir OK.
    Attachment dir OK.
    Plugins OK.

Themes OK.
    Default language OK.
    Base URL detected as: http://mtest.gbs-korea.com/src (location base autodetected)
Checking outgoing mail service....
    sendmail OK
Checking IMAP service....
    IMAP server ready (* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.)

Capabilities: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN

Checking internationalization (i18n) settings...
     gettext - Gettext functions are available. On some systems you must have appropriate system locales compiled.
     mbstring - Mbstring functions are available.
     recode - Recode functions are unavailable.
     iconv - Iconv functions are available.

timezone - Webmail users can change their time zone settings.
Checking database functions...
    not using database functionality.

Congratulations, your SquirrelMail setup looks fine to me!

Login now

### ...

but, i can't access my account because below message.

> ERROR:
>   ERROR: Connection dropped by IMAP server.

....

how to solve it problem?

Answer (score 5):

To resolve such an issue:

Edit the file `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` and add the following line in the IMAP section:

```
protocol imap {

mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u

}
```

Restart dovecot:

`/etc/init.d/dovecot restart`

That’s it.

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 6.6 and Centos 7
nano /etc/postfix/main.cf

change parameter to :

home_mailbox = mail/

nano  /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf

set parameter to:
mail_location = maildir:~/mail

sudo service postfix restart
sudo service dovecot restart

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried telnet to the server to port 143

try "telnet hostname _or_IP 143"

Make sure that the entered E-mail account mailbox is exists in the server. Also make sure that the its MX is local domain if the domain points to the server in which you have installed squirrel mail. In case if its using remote MX then you need to use a domain that is having MX on the current server.

dig +trace domain_name MX will show you the domain's MX record.

Answer (score -1):

mailbox needs to exist, e.g. do it like this:
-first install mailx
-then issue following command (replace 'mail@example.org' with the email-address you use to log in to squirrelmail)

```
# mailx mail@example.org
```

-then type subject of your choice and hit enter
-then type text of your choice and hit enter
-finally hit ctrl+d

now it should be possible to log in